# Rails, undefined method `total_pages' #<PG::Result:0x007f3ede39dae0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Having issue while passing limit per paje display 50 records.

```
if params[:limit].present? && params[:offset].present?
  offset_value = (params[:offset].to_i - 1) * params[:limit].to_i
  limit << " LIMIT #{params[:limit].to_i} OFFSET #{offset_value}"
elsif params[:limit].present?
  limit << " LIMIT #{params[:limit].to_i}"
else
  if params[:offset].present?
    offset_value = (params[:offset].to_i - 1) * 50
    limit << " LIMIT 50 OFFSET #{offset_value}"
  else
    limit << " LIMIT 50"
  end
end

query << "
    select pp.id, 
    ud.last_name || ' ' || ud.first_name as full_name, 
    pp.image_file_name, 
    pp.gender_type ,
    pp.no_of_view_for_last_30_days ,
    pp.no_of_likes ,
    pp.no_of_comments, 
    pp.tenpo_name_display, 
    pp.online_open ,
    pp.online_comment from product pp 
    inner join user_details ud on pp.user_id = ud.user_id 
    inner join user_labels ul on ul.user_id = ud.user_id 
    where pp.flag = false and end_dt is null"

@posts = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query + limit)
```

having error in view, below line.

```
<%= will_paginate @posts, :renderer => BootstrapPagination::Rails  %>
```

trying to make pagination, but having error like total_pages after passing objet to view.

Comment: usingt a pagination gem for your rails application! search pagy or kaminari

Comment: @Spikie Yes, Used, still giving error like total_pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done with this. get total count from query.

```
query << " select count(*) OVER() AS total_count,
pp.id, 
ud.last_name || ' ' || ud.first_name as full_name, 
pp.image_file_name, 
pp.gender_type ,
pp.no_of_view_for_last_30_days ,
pp.no_of_likes ,
pp.no_of_comments, 
pp.tenpo_name_display, 
pp.online_open ,
pp.online_comment from product pp 
inner join user_details ud on pp.user_id = ud.user_id 
inner join user_labels ul on ul.user_id = ud.user_id 
where pp.flag = false and end_dt is null"

    offset = params[:page].present? ? (params[:page].to_i - 1) * 30 : 0
    @posts = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query + 'limit 30 offset ' + offset.to_s )
    posts_count = !@posts.nil? ? @posts.first["total_count"] : 0
    @post_count = @posts.to_a.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30, total_entries: posts_count)
```

passing param as total_entries to pagination. It's work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to use `will_paginate` gem, aren't you?

If that's the case, you're doing too much in your controller. `will_paginate` is supposed to do all those calculations (offsets etc.) for you:

```
@posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Please note also that https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/will_paginate-bootstrap (which it seems you're trying to use) is no longer maintained.

Comment: I have that gem and i am trying to paginate `@posts = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query + limit)` this data.

Comment: This is not how you're supposed to paginate it. Instead of running `@posts = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` run `@posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page]) `